# jQuery to automatically pre-select multiple options from several drop down lists based on user selection from another drop down list

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how to accomplish the following:

Using jQuery, Javascript, or additionally Ajax, PHP, MYSQL if need be.

I need to have multiple drop down list options automatically selected based on a user selection from another drop down list. This will save a signifiant amount of time when completing the form.

Below is the HTML form code, I have removed all non relevant form elements other than the drop down lists that I'm talking about, in order to avoid confusion.

To be specific, when a user selects an option from the Position drop down list, I want all the Attribute Type drop down lists, to be automatically selected with that particular positions specific set of attributes. There are 8 specific attributes associated with each position.

**Position Specific Attributes:**

- **QB** - SPD, AGI, INJ, AWR, TPOW, ELUS, TACC, TDEP
- **HB** - SPD, AGI, ACC, AWR, CARY, TRCK, ELUS, BCV
- **FB** - SPD, AGI, AWR, TRCK, CTCH, RBST, RBFT, IMPB
- **WR** - SPD, AGI, AWR, RRUN, CTCH, CINT, SCAT, RLS
- **TE** - SPD, AGI, AWR, RRUN, CTCH, CINT, SCAT, RBST
- **LT** - STR, AWR, PBST, PBFT, RBST, RBFT, IMPB, INJ
- **LG** - STR, AWR, PBST, PBFT, RBST, RBFT, IMPB, INJ
- **C**  - STR, AWR, PBST, PBFT, RBST, RBFT, IMPB, INJ
- **RG** - STR, AWR, PBST, PBFT, RBST, RBFT, IMPB, INJ
- **RT** - STR, AWR, PBST, PBFT, RBST, RBFT, IMPB, INJ
- **LE** - SPD, AWR, STR, TCKL, PMOV, FMOV, BSHD, PUR
- **RE** - SPD, AWR, STR, TCKL, PMOV, FMOV, BSHD, PUR
- **DT** - SPD, AWR, STR, TCKL, PMOV, FMOV, BSHD, PUR
- **LOLB** - SPD, AGI, AWR, TCKL, BSHD, HP, PREC, PUR
- **MLB**  - SPD, AGI, AWR, TCKL, BSHD, HP, PREC, PUR
- **ROLB** - SPD, AGI, AWR, TCKL, BSHD, HP, PREC, PUR
- **CB** - SPD, AGI, AWR, TCKL, MCOV, ZCOV, PRES, PREC
- **FS** - SPD, AGI, AWR, TCKL, MCOV, ZCOV, PRES, PREC
- **SS** - SPD, AGI, AWR, TCKL, MCOV, ZCOV, PRES, PREC
- **K**  - AWR, KPOW, KACC
- **P**  - AWR, KPOW, KACC
- **HC** - MOT, KNO, OFF, DEF, WOR, CHM

  ```
  <!-- POSITIONS -->
  <div class="styled">
    <select id="position">
      <option selected disabled>Select Position</option>
      <optgroup label="OFFENSE">
        <option value="QB">QB</option>
        <option value="HB">HB</option>
        <option value="FB">FB</option>
        <option value="WR">WR</option>
        <option value="TE">TE</option>
        <option value="LT">LT</option>
        <option value="LG">LG</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="RG">RG</option>
        <option value="RT">RT</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="DEFENSE">
        <option value="LE">LE</option>
        <option value="RE">RE</option>
        <option value="DT">DT</option>
        <option value="LOLB">LOLB</option>
        <option value="MLB">MLB</option>
        <option value="ROLB">ROLB</option>
        <option value="CB">CB</option>
        <option value="FS">FS</option>
        <option value="SS">SS</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="SPECIAL TEAMS">
        <option value="K">K</option>
        <option value="P">P</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="COACH">
        <option value="HC">HC</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </div>

  <!-- ATTRIBUTES -->
  <div class="styled">
    <select id="attribute_type_1">
      <option selected disabled>Select Attribute Type</option>
      <option value="SPD">SPD</option>
      <option value="STR">STR</option>
      <option value="AGI">AGI</option>
      <option value="ACC">ACC</option>
      <option value="AWR">AWR</option>
      <option value="TRCK">TRCK</option>
      <option value="ELUS">ELUS</option>
      <option value="BCV">BCV</option>
      <option value="STIF">STIF</option>
      <option value="SMOV">SMOV</option>
      <option value="JMOV">JMOV</option>
      <option value="CARY">CARY</option>
      <option value="CTCH">CTCH</option>
      <option value="RRUN">RRUN</option>
      <option value="CINT">CINT</option>
      <option value="SCAT">SCAT</option>
      <option value="RLS">RLS</option>
      <option value="JUMP">JUMP</option>
      <option value="TPOW">TPOW</option>
      <option value="TACC">TACC</option>
      <option value="TSHT">TSHT</option>
      <option value="TMID">TMID</option>
      <option value="TDEP">TDEP</option>
      <option value="TRUN">TRUN</option>
      <option value="PACT">PACT</option>
      <option value="TCKL">TCKL</option>
      <option value="HP">HP</option>
      <option value="PMOV">PMOV</option>
      <option value="FMOV">FMOV</option>
      <option value="BSHD">BSHD</option>
      <option value="PUR">PUR</option>
      <option value="PREC">PREC</option>
      <option value="MCOV">MCOV</option>
      <option value="ZCOV">ZCOV</option>
      <option value="PRES">PRES</option>
      <option value="RBST">RBST</option>
      <option value="RBFT">RBFT</option>
      <option value="PBST">PBST</option>
      <option value="PBFT">PBFT</option>
      <option value="IMPB">IMPB</option>
      <option value="KPOW">KPOW</option>
      <option value="KACC">KACC</option>
      <option value="STA">STA</option>
      <option value="INJ">INJ</option>
      <option value="MOT">MOT</option>
      <option value="KNO">KNO</option>
      <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
      <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
      <option value="WOR">WOR</option>
      <option value="CHM">CHM</option>
    </select>

    <select id="attribute_type_2">
      <option selected disabled>Select Attribute Type</option>
      <option value="SPD">SPD</option>
      <option value="STR">STR</option>
      <option value="AGI">AGI</option>
      <option value="ACC">ACC</option>
      <option value="AWR">AWR</option>
      <option value="TRCK">TRCK</option>
      <option value="ELUS">ELUS</option>
      <option value="BCV">BCV</option>
      <option value="STIF">STIF</option>
      <option value="SMOV">SMOV</option>
      <option value="JMOV">JMOV</option>
      <option value="CARY">CARY</option>
      <option value="CTCH">CTCH</option>
      <option value="RRUN">RRUN</option>
      <option value="CINT">CINT</option>
      <option value="SCAT">SCAT</option>
      <option value="RLS">RLS</option>
      <option value="JUMP">JUMP</option>
      <option value="TPOW">TPOW</option>
      <option value="TACC">TACC</option>
      <option value="TSHT">TSHT</option>
      <option value="TMID">TMID</option>
      <option value="TDEP">TDEP</option>
      <option value="TRUN">TRUN</option>
      <option value="PACT">PACT</option>
      <option value="TCKL">TCKL</option>
      <option value="HP">HP</option>
      <option value="PMOV">PMOV</option>
      <option value="FMOV">FMOV</option>
      <option value="BSHD">BSHD</option>
      <option value="PUR">PUR</option>
      <option value="PREC">PREC</option>
      <option value="MCOV">MCOV</option>
      <option value="ZCOV">ZCOV</option>
      <option value="PRES">PRES</option>
      <option value="RBST">RBST</option>
      <option value="RBFT">RBFT</option>
      <option value="PBST">PBST</option>
      <option value="PBFT">PBFT</option>
      <option value="IMPB">IMPB</option>
      <option value="KPOW">KPOW</option>
      <option value="KACC">KACC</option>
      <option value="STA">STA</option>
      <option value="INJ">INJ</option>
      <option value="MOT">MOT</option>
      <option value="KNO">KNO</option>
      <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
      <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
      <option value="WOR">WOR</option>
      <option value="CHM">CHM</option>
    </select>

    <select id="attribute_type_3">
      <option selected disabled>Select Attribute Type</option>
      <option value="SPD">SPD</option>
      <option value="STR">STR</option>
      <option value="AGI">AGI</option>
      <option value="ACC">ACC</option>
      <option value="AWR">AWR</option>
      <option value="TRCK">TRCK</option>
      <option value="ELUS">ELUS</option>
      <option value="BCV">BCV</option>
      <option value="STIF">STIF</option>
      <option value="SMOV">SMOV</option>
      <option value="JMOV">JMOV</option>
      <option value="CARY">CARY</option>
      <option value="CTCH">CTCH</option>
      <option value="RRUN">RRUN</option>
      <option value="CINT">CINT</option>
      <option value="SCAT">SCAT</option>
      <option value="RLS">RLS</option>
      <option value="JUMP">JUMP</option>
      <option value="TPOW">TPOW</option>
      <option value="TACC">TACC</option>
      <option value="TSHT">TSHT</option>
      <option value="TMID">TMID</option>
      <option value="TDEP">TDEP</option>
      <option value="TRUN">TRUN</option>
      <option value="PACT">PACT</option>
      <option value="TCKL">TCKL</option>
      <option value="HP">HP</option>
      <option value="PMOV">PMOV</option>
      <option value="FMOV">FMOV</option>
      <option value="BSHD">BSHD</option>
      <option value="PUR">PUR</option>
      <option value="PREC">PREC</option>
      <option value="MCOV">MCOV</option>
      <option value="ZCOV">ZCOV</option>
      <option value="PRES">PRES</option>
      <option value="RBST">RBST</option>
      <option value="RBFT">RBFT</option>
      <option value="PBST">PBST</option>
      <option value="PBFT">PBFT</option>
      <option value="IMPB">IMPB</option>
      <option value="KPOW">KPOW</option>
      <option value="KACC">KACC</option>
      <option value="STA">STA</option>
      <option value="INJ">INJ</option>
      <option value="MOT">MOT</option>
      <option value="KNO">KNO</option>
      <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
      <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
      <option value="WOR">WOR</option>
      <option value="CHM">CHM</option>
    </select>

    <select id="attribute_type_4">
      <option selected disabled>Select Attribute Type</option>
      <option value="SPD">SPD</option>
      <option value="STR">STR</option>
      <option value="AGI">AGI</option>
      <option value="ACC">ACC</option>
      <option value="AWR">AWR</option>
      <option value="TRCK">TRCK</option>
      <option value="ELUS">ELUS</option>
      <option value="BCV">BCV</option>
      <option value="STIF">STIF</option>
      <option value="SMOV">SMOV</option>
      <option value="JMOV">JMOV</option>
      <option value="CARY">CARY</option>
      <option value="CTCH">CTCH</option>
      <option value="RRUN">RRUN</option>
      <option value="CINT">CINT</option>
      <option value="SCAT">SCAT</option>
      <option value="RLS">RLS</option>
      <option value="JUMP">JUMP</option>
      <option value="TPOW">TPOW</option>
      <option value="TACC">TACC</option>
      <option value="TSHT">TSHT</option>
      <option value="TMID">TMID</option>
      <option value="TDEP">TDEP</option>
      <option value="TRUN">TRUN</option>
      <option value="PACT">PACT</option>
      <option value="TCKL">TCKL</option>
      <option value="HP">HP</option>
      <option value="PMOV">PMOV</option>
      <option value="FMOV">FMOV</option>
      <option value="BSHD">BSHD</option>
      <option value="PUR">PUR</option>
      <option value="PREC">PREC</option>
      <option value="MCOV">MCOV</option>
      <option value="ZCOV">ZCOV</option>
      <option value="PRES">PRES</option>
      <option value="RBST">RBST</option>
      <option value="RBFT">RBFT</option>
      <option value="PBST">PBST</option>
      <option value="PBFT">PBFT</option>
      <option value="IMPB">IMPB</option>
      <option value="KPOW">KPOW</option>
      <option value="KACC">KACC</option>
      <option value="STA">STA</option>
      <option value="INJ">INJ</option>
      <option value="MOT">MOT</option>
      <option value="KNO">KNO</option>
      <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
      <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
      <option value="WOR">WOR</option>
      <option value="CHM">CHM</option>
    </select>

    <select id="attribute_type_5">
      <option selected disabled>Select Attribute Type</option>
      <option value="SPD">SPD</option>
      <option value="STR">STR</option>
      <option value="AGI">AGI</option>
      <option value="ACC">ACC</option>
      <option value="AWR">AWR</option>
      <option value="TRCK">TRCK</option>
      <option value="ELUS">ELUS</option>
      <option value="BCV">BCV</option>
      <option value="STIF">STIF</option>
      <option value="SMOV">SMOV</option>
      <option value="JMOV">JMOV</option>
      <option value="CARY">CARY</option>
      <option value="CTCH">CTCH</option>
      <option value="RRUN">RRUN</option>
      <option value="CINT">CINT</option>
      <option value="SCAT">SCAT</option>
      <option value="RLS">RLS</option>
      <option value="JUMP">JUMP</option>
      <option value="TPOW">TPOW</option>
      <option value="TACC">TACC</option>
      <option value="TSHT">TSHT</option>
      <option value="TMID">TMID</option>
      <option value="TDEP">TDEP</option>
      <option value="TRUN">TRUN</option>
      <option value="PACT">PACT</option>
      <option value="TCKL">TCKL</option>
      <option value="HP">HP</option>
      <option value="PMOV">PMOV</option>
      <option value="FMOV">FMOV</option>
      <option value="BSHD">BSHD</option>
      <option value="PUR">PUR</option>
      <option value="PREC">PREC</option>
      <option value="MCOV">MCOV</option>
      <option value="ZCOV">ZCOV</option>
      <option value="PRES">PRES</option>
      <option value="RBST">RBST</option>
      <option value="RBFT">RBFT</option>
      <option value="PBST">PBST</option>
      <option value="PBFT">PBFT</option>
      <option value="IMPB">IMPB</option>
      <option value="KPOW">KPOW</option>
      <option value="KACC">KACC</option>
      <option value="STA">STA</option>
      <option value="INJ">INJ</option>
      <option value="MOT">MOT</option>
      <option value="KNO">KNO</option>
      <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
      <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
      <option value="WOR">WOR</option>
      <option value="CHM">CHM</option>
    </select>

    <select id="attribute_type_6">
      <option selected disabled>Select Attribute Type</option>
      <option value="SPD">SPD</option>
      <option value="STR">STR</option>
      <option value="AGI">AGI</option>
      <option value="ACC">ACC</option>
      <option value="AWR">AWR</option>
      <option value="TRCK">TRCK</option>
      <option value="ELUS">ELUS</option>
      <option value="BCV">BCV</option>
      <option value="STIF">STIF</option>
      <option value="SMOV">SMOV</option>
      <option value="JMOV">JMOV</option>
      <option value="CARY">CARY</option>
      <option value="CTCH">CTCH</option>
      <option value="RRUN">RRUN</option>
      <option value="CINT">CINT</option>
      <option value="SCAT">SCAT</option>
      <option value="RLS">RLS</option>
      <option value="JUMP">JUMP</option>
      <option value="TPOW">TPOW</option>
      <option value="TACC">TACC</option>
      <option value="TSHT">TSHT</option>
      <option value="TMID">TMID</option>
      <option value="TDEP">TDEP</option>
      <option value="TRUN">TRUN</option>
      <option value="PACT">PACT</option>
      <option value="TCKL">TCKL</option>
      <option value="HP">HP</option>
      <option value="PMOV">PMOV</option>
      <option value="FMOV">FMOV</option>
      <option value="BSHD">BSHD</option>
      <option value="PUR">PUR</option>
      <option value="PREC">PREC</option>
      <option value="MCOV">MCOV</option>
      <option value="ZCOV">ZCOV</option>
      <option value="PRES">PRES</option>
      <option value="RBST">RBST</option>
      <option value="RBFT">RBFT</option>
      <option value="PBST">PBST</option>
      <option value="PBFT">PBFT</option>
      <option value="IMPB">IMPB</option>
      <option value="KPOW">KPOW</option>
      <option value="KACC">KACC</option>
      <option value="STA">STA</option>
      <option value="INJ">INJ</option>
      <option value="MOT">MOT</option>
      <option value="KNO">KNO</option>
      <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
      <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
      <option value="WOR">WOR</option>
      <option value="CHM">CHM</option>
    </select>

    <select id="attribute_type_7">
      <option selected disabled>Select Attribute Type</option>
      <option value="SPD">SPD</option>
      <option value="STR">STR</option>
      <option value="AGI">AGI</option>
      <option value="ACC">ACC</option>
      <option value="AWR">AWR</option>
      <option value="TRCK">TRCK</option>
      <option value="ELUS">ELUS</option>
      <option value="BCV">BCV</option>
      <option value="STIF">STIF</option>
      <option value="SMOV">SMOV</option>
      <option value="JMOV">JMOV</option>
      <option value="CARY">CARY</option>
      <option value="CTCH">CTCH</option>
      <option value="RRUN">RRUN</option>
      <option value="CINT">CINT</option>
      <option value="SCAT">SCAT</option>
      <option value="RLS">RLS</option>
      <option value="JUMP">JUMP</option>
      <option value="TPOW">TPOW</option>
      <option value="TACC">TACC</option>
      <option value="TSHT">TSHT</option>
      <option value="TMID">TMID</option>
      <option value="TDEP">TDEP</option>
      <option value="TRUN">TRUN</option>
      <option value="PACT">PACT</option>
      <option value="TCKL">TCKL</option>
      <option value="HP">HP</option>
      <option value="PMOV">PMOV</option>
      <option value="FMOV">FMOV</option>
      <option value="BSHD">BSHD</option>
      <option value="PUR">PUR</option>
      <option value="PREC">PREC</option>
      <option value="MCOV">MCOV</option>
      <option value="ZCOV">ZCOV</option>
      <option value="PRES">PRES</option>
      <option value="RBST">RBST</option>
      <option value="RBFT">RBFT</option>
      <option value="PBST">PBST</option>
      <option value="PBFT">PBFT</option>
      <option value="IMPB">IMPB</option>
      <option value="KPOW">KPOW</option>
      <option value="KACC">KACC</option>
      <option value="STA">STA</option>
      <option value="INJ">INJ</option>
      <option value="MOT">MOT</option>
      <option value="KNO">KNO</option>
      <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
      <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
      <option value="WOR">WOR</option>
      <option value="CHM">CHM</option>
    </select>

    <select id="attribute_type_8">
      <option selected disabled>Select Attribute Type</option>
      <option value="SPD">SPD</option>
      <option value="STR">STR</option>
      <option value="AGI">AGI</option>
      <option value="ACC">ACC</option>
      <option value="AWR">AWR</option>
      <option value="TRCK">TRCK</option>
      <option value="ELUS">ELUS</option>
      <option value="BCV">BCV</option>
      <option value="STIF">STIF</option>
      <option value="SMOV">SMOV</option>
      <option value="JMOV">JMOV</option>
      <option value="CARY">CARY</option>
      <option value="CTCH">CTCH</option>
      <option value="RRUN">RRUN</option>
      <option value="CINT">CINT</option>
      <option value="SCAT">SCAT</option>
      <option value="RLS">RLS</option>
      <option value="JUMP">JUMP</option>
      <option value="TPOW">TPOW</option>
      <option value="TACC">TACC</option>
      <option value="TSHT">TSHT</option>
      <option value="TMID">TMID</option>
      <option value="TDEP">TDEP</option>
      <option value="TRUN">TRUN</option>
      <option value="PACT">PACT</option>
      <option value="TCKL">TCKL</option>
      <option value="HP">HP</option>
      <option value="PMOV">PMOV</option>
      <option value="FMOV">FMOV</option>
      <option value="BSHD">BSHD</option>
      <option value="PUR">PUR</option>
      <option value="PREC">PREC</option>
      <option value="MCOV">MCOV</option>
      <option value="ZCOV">ZCOV</option>
      <option value="PRES">PRES</option>
      <option value="RBST">RBST</option>
      <option value="RBFT">RBFT</option>
      <option value="PBST">PBST</option>
      <option value="PBFT">PBFT</option>
      <option value="IMPB">IMPB</option>
      <option value="KPOW">KPOW</option>
      <option value="KACC">KACC</option>
      <option value="STA">STA</option>
      <option value="INJ">INJ</option>
      <option value="MOT">MOT</option>
      <option value="KNO">KNO</option>
      <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
      <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
      <option value="WOR">WOR</option>
      <option value="CHM">CHM</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way that comes to mind is the following:

```
var positions = {
    QB : ['SPD', 'AGI', 'INJ', 'AWR', 'TPOW', 'ELUS', 'TACC', 'TDEP'],
    HB : ['SPD', 'AGI', 'ACC', 'AWR', 'CARY', 'TRCK', 'ELUS', 'BCV'],
    FB : ['SPD', 'AGI', 'AWR', 'TRCK', 'CTCH', 'RBST', 'RBFT', 'IMPB']
    // fill in the rest of this object yourself
}

$('#position').change(function(){
        // caching the selected value:
    var v = this.value,
        // retrieving the array stored under the relevant key:
        arr = positions[v],
        // getting all the select elements whose 'id' starts with the string:
        attribs = $('select[id^="attribute_type_"]');
    // iterating each of those selects:
    $.each(attribs, function(i,v){
        /* finding the 'option' whose value is equal to that stored in the array
           at the index point, and setting that to be selected: */
        $(v).find('option[value="' + arr[i] + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/z6wVB/).

Note that in the above demo there seems to be a typo, in that the element with id `attribute_type_7` doesn't get a selected `option` (which should be 'TACC' according to your provided data, but there *is* a 'KACC', so, typo?).

The above amended to use `each()` rather than `jQuery.each()` (or `$.each()`):

```
$('#position').change(function(){
    var v = this.value,
        arr = positions[v];
    $('select[id^="attribute_type_"]').each(function(i){
        $(this).find('option[value="' + arr[i] + '"]').prop('selected',true);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/z6wVB/).

References:

- [attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribue-equals-selector/).
- [attribute-starts-with (`[attribute^="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribue-starts-with-selector/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Yes that was a typo on my part... sorry.

Comment: No problem at all! Barring the typo, then, does this seem to fit your needs? (Though I realise that the answer is incomplete, in that I've not transferred the full range of data to the object.)

Comment: I just edited all the attribute option lists to include TACC. So it was more than a TYPO, I actually left an entire attribute out of the list... lol

Comment: Yes, that answers/solves my problem completely... THANK YOU very much. I really appreciated your help. Two thumbs up from a SGT in the U.S. Marines... ooh-rah!